# Qt Mac OS X: using QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA and/with custom targets

Tags: macos, qt, makefile, qmake, qt5.7

I'm dealing with a build problem for my Qt desktop application. I'm using **QT 5.7**.

As far as I know, for qt mac applications, I need to use **QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA to bundle all the resources into the .app**, so I used it. I also **defined custom target**s for the make file which runs an external command(rcc) which **generates some .rcc** files that need to be copied into the .app bundle.

```
...
CMD_RCC += "rcc -binary "$${QRC_FILE}" -o "$${RCC_FILE}

creatercc.commands = $$CMD_RCC
creatercc-check.commands = $$CMD_RCC
creatercc-make_first.commands = $$CMD_RCC
creatercc-make_default.commands = $$CMD_RCC
creatercc-make_all.commands = $$CMD_RCC
creatercc-qmake_all.commands = $$CMD_RCC

QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS *= creatercc creatercc-check creatercc-make_default creatercc-make_first creatercc-make_all creatercc-qmake_all creatercc-clean creatercc-distclean
PRE_TARGETDEPS *= creatercc

macx{
    DEPLOYDIR = $$PWD/deploy

    LAUNCHER_THEMES.files = \
        $$PWD/deploy/themes/res.rcc
    LAUNCHER_THEMES.path = Contents/Resources/themes
    QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA += LAUNCHER_THEMES
}
```

**The problem** is that I receive an **error at compile** time which suggests that the **.app bundle could not find the.rcc** file, meaning that the .rcc file was not generated! However I tested my custom target(creatercc) without QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA and it generates the .rcc file so I conclude that **.app bundle wants to be created before the .rcc creation** so that's why the bundle cannot find the .rcc file.

**The question is**: how to make sure that the predefined target run first, before QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA, and that QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA waits until the predefined target command ended it's execution? Thanks

Comment: No idea what the interaction between QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS, PRE_TARGETDEPS and QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA are, but as a more general comment, the common way for generate files would be to add a QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS (see [qmake manual](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#adding-compilers))

Comment: Thank you for the manual but it didn't help